# Unmountable boot volume after diskmgmt partition

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, hardware-failure

After i shrank my c drive by 60gb in diskmgmt and made a spare partition, all of the other partitions turned light green.

only after i started up my computer the next day i got an inviting blue screen of death saying UNMOUNTABLE_BOOT_VOLUME and a bunch of numbers. I am on a macbook pro so i have 2 partitions for windows and mac. I couldn't boot into linux form usb so i put my hdd into another old computer to work from. I have tried chkdisk /r c: and it doesn't do anything.

Any advice is appreciated before i decide to re install.

Comment: eh, these kind of things, much better to just reinstall

Comment: id rather not because it would take several hours (9 hours) to reinstall windows and all of the programs

Comment: if you could be slightly more descriptive then, is it always BSOD'ing on you? If that's the case then you may be in for a problem. You can try salvaging the files across the partition. Either way if you could clear up your question slightly more it would be helpful

Comment: yes i say in the question that it gives me a blue screen of death and the it says UNMOUNTABLE_BOOT_VOLUME  when i boot in linux and start gparted it says the whole volume is unallocated

Comment: just found out i have a dynamic ntfs partition

Comment: well either way if you're not being allowed into the OS, you are going to have to perform a recovery off a boot disc. Verify the disk and repair if you can, and lets see what happens from there.

Comment: yeah, i need a linux boot usb with a recovery tool

Comment: i think Linux bootable discs have a recovery tool in built, check the disk utility listing for it on their site